# Why does this paper use 1/cm for units of frequency?

Tags: units, frequency, dimensional-analysis, wavelength

Reading [this paper from 1963](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.129.1566) $^*$, they use units of cm$^{-1}$ for frequency.

Here is an excerpt:
[image]

It doesn't seem like wave number, as they clearly call it frequency. What's going on here?

$^*$ Sievers III, A. J., and M. Tinkham. "Far infrared antiferromagnetic resonance in MnO and NiO." *Physical Review* 129.4 (1963): 1566.

Comment: Frequency is proportional to wavenumber, it is straightforward to convert kayser to hertz.

Comment: @Pieter Why would they call it frequency?

Comment: Because it is the same thing. An energy difference.

Comment: The same reason you might say “a 1 kilogram weight”.

Comment: All explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber#In_spectroscopy

Comment: Per @Farcher suggestions, wikipedia says: "*A wavenumber in inverse cm can be converted to a frequency in GHz by multiplying by 29.9792458 (the speed of light in centimeters per nanosecond).*"

Comment: It's probably also relevant that the unit hertz, with its convenient derived unit of gigahertz, didn't come into wide use until roughly the 1960's. So up to that time you would have had to talk about "kilo megacycles per second" to discuss frequencies in this band, and 10s of inverse cm would have been much more convenient. Even after SI became commonly used, some fields have continued to work in wavenumber  rather than GHz or THz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People working in the infrared or optical region tend to sometimes, depending on what school of thought they come from, use a unit called *wavenumber*, which is the reciprocal wavelength in centimeters, $\frac{1}{\lambda_{centimeter}}$.

This is still a frequency, but instead of oscillations per second, it is oscillations per centimeter.

This unit is also called a [Kayser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber#In_spectroscopy). *Wavenumber* and *Kayser* are commonly used when working with spectroscopy/diffraction.

Comment: soooo, why call it frequency? That's my question

Comment: @axsvl77 It is still a frequency, but the unit of the frequency is not oscillations per second, but rather oscillations per centimeter.

Answer (score 3):

A frequency is a number of oscillations, but you need to specify the unit you're refering to : is it oscillations per a given duration (temporal frequency) or per a given length (spatial frequency). Today "frequency" implies a temporal frequency, and we use the word "wave number" for the spatial frequency, allowing us to go away with the adjective. That was not always the case.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes physicists use (lenghts)$^{-1}$ to indicate frequencies, expecially in spectroscopy...

As you well now, $\omega = 2\pi \nu$ and $c = \lambda \nu$ so that

$\omega = 2\pi \frac{c}{\lambda}$ which is proportional to $ \lambda ^ {-1},$ since $c$ is a constant.

So when one says $\omega_1 = 29 cm^{-1}$ is actually saying $\omega_1 = c_{cgs}29 s^{-1} $ where $c_{cgs}$ is the speed of light in the cgs system

Answer (score 2):

If you suppose c=1, then 'centimetre' is the time it takes for light to cross a centimetre, and a count of cycles per centimetre is something that can be done in nature, and also relates to the frequency in cycles per second.