# What does it mean when frequency has dimension of (1/cm)?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, spectroscopy

I have to solve this problem.

> Let WDOS (weighted DOS) be
> $$ \rho (\omega) = A \omega e^{- \omega / \omega _0}\ \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$
> where $\omega _0 = 30\ \color{red}{\text{cm}^{-1}}$ and $A$ is a constant.
>
> The amplitude of fluctuation $D$ is given as
> $$ D^2 (T) = \int _0 ^\infty \rho (\omega) \omega ^2 \text{coth} \left( \frac{\hbar \omega}{2 k_B T} \right) d\omega .\ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
>
> 1. Numerically determine the value of $A$, assuming $D = 100\ \text{cm}^{-1}$ when $T = 300\ \text{K}$.
> 2. ... (A middle level problem.)
> 3. ... (A higher level problem.)

I don't even understand the problem. If $\omega _0$ has dimension of cm${}^{-1}$, the frequency $\omega$ should have the same dimension to make $\omega / \omega _0$ dimensionless in eq.(1). If so, however, $\hbar \omega / 2 k_B T$ in eq.(2) **does** have dimension, which is so strange that we cannot determine dimension of $\text{coth} \left( \frac{\hbar \omega}{2 k_B T} \right)$.

Is the problem incorrect? But please note that, in the field of spectroscopy, sometimes it seems frequency has dimension of length. For example, see [this plot](http://imagebank.osa.org/getImage.xqy?img=dTcqLmxhcmdlLGpvc2FiLTE3LTEtMTIwLWcwMDM) from [this paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/josab/abstract.cfm?uri=josab-17-1-120).

How can we handle frequency whose dimension is cm${}^{-1}$?

---

For the future reader:

I found a related post [*Why does this paper use 1/cm for units of frequency?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418033/why-does-this-paper-use-1-cm-for-units-of-frequency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the units of $\hbar$ have also been adjusted to match.

Multiply your frequency by $c$ to get a conventional angular frequency in rad/s, or multiply $\hbar \mapsto\hbar c$ to get the appropriate units for $\hbar$.

Comment: Thank you really much. I understand now.